# Is there a simple cron command that I can enter on cPanel to trigger scheduled jobs?

Tags: wordpress, scheduled-job

I'm trying to set up a cron job on cPanel for Civicrm 5.9 running on Wordpress 5.1.1.  I've read so many "you need to do this" "you need to do that" my head is spinning.  Is there a simple command line that I can enter on cPanel to trigger scheduled jobs? Job.execute isn't getting the job done.  I'm not a programmer so I rely on step by step or solid examples and so far haven't found any that make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is a difficult question to answer is that it depends so much on your hosting provider.  If you have a hosting provider, I would ask them for assistance.  If not, you may want to find someone in https://chat.civicrm.org who can assist.  There are also third-party "webcron" services available.